# ngGrid - remove row

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have been looking for an example on how to implement a button to remove a selected row, but I couldn't find anything useful so far.

Can anyone please give me a hint? Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkeM4PtBHHG7PAI1a4rj) example.

The function I implement acts weird, as it removes other rows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not a proper way to delete any row

Try like this:

```
$scope.removeRow = function() {
   var index = this.row.rowIndex;
   $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
   $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvSrMqz9yuIAdcWIpsTS?p=preview) `-->` Its working and tested

Comment: Well, try and delete Moroni and you'll see that it removes the last row. So basically it removes the last row every time (similar to pop for queue).

Comment: Hey Dado, I have found the problem. That is with the argument I send through my button, which was $index. If you change that to 'row', it will work correctly. Thank you for your answer mate.

Comment: @Mehran Plunker itself looks down right now! i think it will resume after some hours :)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak you plnkr is not working all the time. If you press on name header the order of the entries reverses; Press on any remove button, then the entry that was on that row previous to hitting the header will be removed since you remove $scope.myDate based on the current index value!

Answer (score 6):

thanks for the hint but
I tried the snippet and it doesn't work
so I changed it in

```
var removeTemplate = '<input type="button" value="remove" ng-click="removeRow()" />';
$scope.removeRow = function() {;
                    var index = this.row.rowIndex;
                    alert(index);
                    $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                };
```

and it works like a charme :)
Hope this help.

Comment: Works for me!

Note - If you have ```enableCellEditOnFocus: true``` for the grid, you will need to set both 
```cellTemplate: removeTemplate``` and 
```editableCellTemplate: removeTemplate``` 
on the ```columnDefs```. Otherwise, the cell appears editable

Answer (score 3):

This might help you, and also this is for deleting multiple rows in the grid.

```
$scope.mySelections = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data :'gridData',
    selectedItems : $scope.mySelections,
    showSelectionCheckbox : true
}

$scope.deleteSelected = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.mySelections, function(rowItem) { 
    $scope.gridData.splice($scope.gridData.indexOf(rowItem),1);
});
}
```

mySelections is the array which has selected rows

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer to this question won't work once the array has been sorted because the row.index changes based on the way the array has been sorted but the original data in the array remains in it's original index.  We must find the correct index in the data array in order to remove the correct row.  The row contains a reference to the original data in row.entity so we can use indexOf to find the correct index.

```
$scope.actionTemplate = '<input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="delete($event);" />';

$scope.delete = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation(); //keep the row from being selected
    $scope.data.selectAll(false); //remove all selections: necessary for issues with the selection array
    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(this.row.entity); //get the correct index to splice
    $scope.metrics.splice(index, 1); //remove the element
};
```

Edit: The original solution may have worked at the time but ng-grid has since been updated and it no longer works.

Comment: Great Answer! Other solutions don't work if you want to remove a single entry once you change how the data is sorted or add a search  option

Answer (score 0):

It might help you

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="deleteApp">
<head>
  <title>Example - www.code-sample.com</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('deleteApp', [])
      .controller('deleteController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
          $scope.Rows = [
            { row: 'RowCount1'},
            { row: 'RowCount2'},
            { row: 'RowCount3'},
            { row: 'RowCount4'},
            { row: 'RowCount5'}];

            $scope.delete = function(index){
              $scope.Rows.splice(index, 1);
            }
      }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="deleteController">
  <div ng-repeat="ro in Rows">
    <div>{{$index + 1}} :  {{ro.row}} <input type="button" value="delete" ng-click="delete($index)" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

showSelectionCheckbox : true ->it adds checkbox to grid
 and 
 $scope.delItem = function() -> it works for both multiple rows or single row selection

```
     $scope.mySelections = [];
                 $scope.gridOptions = {
                     data :'data',
                     selectedItems : $scope.mySelections,
                     showSelectionCheckbox : true
                 } 

 $scope.delItem = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mySelections.length; i++) {
             var index = $scope.data.indexOf($scope.mySelections[i]);
             if (index != -1) {
                 $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
             }
         }
     }
```