# ng-grid original row index

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am customizing a cell template in ng-grid. In that cell, I want to have a button that will trigger some event that needs the row index into the original data array. The template looks like this:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="removeItem(row.rowIndex)">
  <i class="icon-remove"></i>
</button>
```

and `removeItem` is implemented like this:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(rowIndex) { $scope.myList.splice(rowIndex, 1) }
```

This works until I re-sort the grid by clicking on one of the columns. Apparently, rowIndex the visual index of the row, and not the index of the row in the array I supplied.

Is there a way to obtain the actual index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way that i can think of would be to add a property index on the model data itself and  initialize it when you get the data. This way you always have the initial row order. Something like

```
angular.forEach(items,function(item,index){
   item.index=index;
});
```

I don't think the grid provides any such mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [ngGrid - remove row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368314/nggrid-remove-row)

You can find the original index of the element using `indexOf(row.entity)`

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="remove" ng-click="removeRow(row)" />
```

Javascript

```
$scope.removeRow = function(row) {
    var index = $scope.myData.indexOf(row.entity);
    $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[Full example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WpFEOn?p=preview)

Comment: That makes sense, though I'd prefer a solution which is less than linear in time.