# Update ng-grid data by directive when change in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I have created a custom ng-grid by directive. But when I delete an item from list then there is no change occur in ng-grid. But data removes from list successfully. And my pager does not work properly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/D7HWc3snXhpDxM550k7s?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [ngGrid - remove row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368314/nggrid-remove-row)

Comment: Please see my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the length of your array to the variable `Count`. This assignment is not updated automaticaly after declaration. You can use `{{infooo.length}}` directly within your template to show the 'live' value.

Angular then watches the array property for changes and updates the value immedeately after removing the row.

[updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7HWc3snXhpDxM550k7s?p=preview)

Comment: Count is not my problem. Please see my question again.